# Soft Deletion with Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I've done a few changes on my code, because now I want to have a soft deletion instead of a normal one.
I would only need a few JPA annotations for this purpose.
I think I got the right idea, but now I can't even run it because it give the following error:
"""Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Class<?>"""

My CloudProduct.java ( the one with the error ) :

```
package com.proj.my.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityListeners;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

import java.sql.Date;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Filter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Where;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="cloud_product_info")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE cloud_products_info SET deleted = true WHERE id=?")
@FilterDef(name = "deletedProductFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "isDeleted", type = "boolean"))
@Filter(name = "deletedProductFilter", condition = "deleted = :isDeleted")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"}, 
        allowGetters = true)



public class CloudProduct {

    @Id
    private String productId;
    private String productName;
    private String productPrice;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false, name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    private boolean deleted = Boolean.FALSE;


    
    public Boolean getDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public CloudProduct(String productId, String productName, String productPrice, Date createdAt, boolean deleted) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }

    public CloudProduct() {

    } 
    
    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }
    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
    public String getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }
    public void setProductPrice(String productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
}
```

The error is implicit on :

```
@FilterDef(name = "deletedProductFilter", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "isDeleted", type = "boolean"))
```

Specifically on the "type = "boolean" ".
He is my CloudProductController.java

```
package com.proj.my.controller;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;
import com.proj.my.service.CloudProductService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cloudproduct")

public class CloudProductController 
{

    CloudProductService cloudProductService;

    public CloudProductController(CloudProductService cloudProductService)
    {
        this.cloudProductService = cloudProductService;
    }

    @GetMapping("{productId}")
    public CloudProduct getCloudProductDetails(@PathVariable("productId") String productId){
        return cloudProductService.getCloudProduct(productId);
    }


    @PostMapping
    public String createCloudProductDetails(@RequestBody CloudProduct cloudProduct){

        cloudProductService.createCloudProduct(cloudProduct);
        return "Success";
    }

    @PutMapping
    public String updateCloudProductDetails(@RequestBody CloudProduct cloudProduct){

        cloudProductService.updateCloudProduct(cloudProduct);
        return "Updated !";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{productId}")
    public void removeOne(@PathVariable("productId") String productId) {
        cloudProductService.remove(productId);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<CloudProduct> findAll(@RequestParam(value = "isDeleted", required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean isDeleted) {
        return cloudProductService.findAll(isDeleted);
    }



}
```

My CloudProductService.java :

```
package com.proj.my.service;

import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;

public interface CloudProductService {

    public String createCloudProduct(CloudProduct cloudProduct);
    public String updateCloudProduct(CloudProduct cloudProduct);
    public CloudProduct getCloudProduct(String cloudProductId);
    public Iterable<CloudProduct> findAll(boolean isDeleted);
    public void remove(String cloudProductId);
}
```

My CloudProductServiceimpl.java :

```
package com.proj.my.service.impl;

import org.hibernate.Filter;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;
import com.proj.my.repository.CloudProductRepository;
import com.proj.my.service.CloudProductService;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;


@Service
public class CloudProductServiceImpl implements CloudProductService 
{

    CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public CloudProductServiceImpl(CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository) {
    
        this.cloudProductRepository = cloudProductRepository;
    
    }

    @Override
    public String createCloudProduct(CloudProduct cloudProduct){
        cloudProductRepository.save(cloudProduct);
        return "Success";
    }

    @Override
    public String updateCloudProduct(CloudProduct cloudProduct){
        cloudProductRepository.save(cloudProduct);
        return "Success";
    }
        
    @Override
    public CloudProduct getCloudProduct(String cloudProductId){
        return cloudProductRepository.findById(cloudProductId).get();
    }


    public void remove(String cloudProductId){
        cloudProductRepository.deleteById(cloudProductId);
    }

    public Iterable<CloudProduct> findAll(boolean isDeleted){
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Filter filter = session.enableFilter("deletedProductFilter");
        filter.setParameter("isDeleted", isDeleted);
        Iterable<CloudProduct> products =  cloudProductRepository.findAll();
        session.disableFilter("deletedProductFilter");
        return products;
    }

    
}
```

I hope you can help me with this one, THANKS !!!

Comment: I really need some help, whatever I put as the type in Paramdef, I keep getting this error !!! WHY

Comment: Please read the exception stack trace, you will find the root cause of exception.

Comment: Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74823365/type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-string-to-classjava16777233